# Is there a difference between the $R^2$ statistic of a linear regression and pearson correlation?

Tags: regression, correlation, r-squared

Is there any difference between $R^2$ that we get from linear regression and pearson correlation?

Comment: $\sqrt{}$ is your friend :)

Answer (score 3):

A simple answer: in a simple regression model (with a single independent variable) where the independent is interval (not nominal) - Pearsons correlation$^2$ equals $R^2$. But in a multiple regression model it does not. Pearson correlation cannot control for confounders, while a regression model can, thus the explained variance of the dependent variable is a combination of the multiple independent variables' effect.

See: [coefficient of determination](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)